# Unknown OS hostname and product in virt-manager

Tags: linux, linux-kvm, qemu, libvirt

I'm using libvirt on a Fedora 19 host, running various Linux guests with QEMU and KVM hypervisors.

Using the virt-manager GUI, when I look at the guest Overview screen, in the Operating System section I see:

```
Hostname: unknown
Product name: unknown
```

Is this expected?  Is this functionality implemented only for certain hypervisors?  Is there a guest agent I should have installed, or some other installation step I'm missing?

I've done a bit of digging, and a comment associated with a [libvirt patch](http://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2012-July/msg00412.html) implies that it could be a bit of all of these.